# How to calibrate dbfs to db spl?

Tags: javascript, audio, web, web-audio-api

I played a sound with web audio API and used a gainNode to change the volume. When I changed the gainNode's value, the Decibel meter showed a number not expected.

```
context.createGain();
var source=context.createOscillator();
source.frequency.value=1000;
source.start();
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(context.destination);

gainNode.gain.value=Math.pow(10, dbfs/20));

when dbfs=0,the Decibel meter showed 90 dbspl;
when dbfs=-10,the Decibel meter showed 84 dbspl;
when dbfs=-20,the Decibel meter showed 78 dbspl;
when dbfs=-30,the Decibel meter showed 72 dbspl;
when dbfs=-40,the Decibel meter showed 62 dbspl;
when dbfs=-50,the Decibel meter showed 52 dbspl;
```

The actual volume was not changed as expected, was there any mistake in generating the gainNode's value? I want to play the sound at 80 db spl or other specific numbers,what can be the dbfs's value and how to make the gainNode's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One flaw of your approach is that you are using a sine wave tone. You need to use pink noise, otherwise reflections in your room may significantly alter the resulting energy of the sound wave.

Ideally, you should be doing your measurements in an anechoic chamber, or in free field to avoid the interference of reflections.

Another problem may be due to inaccuracy of your SPL meter or non-linearity of your speaker system. Is your SPL meter calibrated, for example?

I would highly recommend reading [this article](http://realtraps.com/art_spl.htm) about SPL measurements.

In general, audio in digital and electrical domain (that is, on your computer and inside the DAC and amplifier) is much more linear and free of distortions than in the acoustic domain (that is, your room, speakers and the microphone), so I would be first looking for problems with them rather than with software. You can try using [REW](http://www.roomeqwizard.com/)  as a reference, and also as a tool to test your sound / mic system first.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply.the reason of useing a sine wave is that is my real demand,I need to play a sound of different frequency to test someone's hearing level. In that case,I used an app runned on iphone6 as the db meter and used thinkpad x201 as the speaker. the iphone6 is 10cm far from the speaker.the db value was very steady while the sound playing. except all inpact,if my code run in ideal conditions，will the dbspl reduce 1db when dbfs reduce 1db？

Comment: I would suggest starting from pink noise anyways to see if it helps. If it does, then it's really about the reflections you are having. BTW, if you are saying the mic is just 10cm away -- are they on a table surface or something like that? That will produce lots of reflections. Try at least putting the devices on stands to make sure there are no reflective surfaces close enough to the sound path.

Comment: thank you very much,your points are all right , my environment is not good enough to do the test